# WCF + Client Authentication by Certificate

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, ssl, certificate

i'm running a WCF service which should only accept clients which are able to authenticate theirself by a ssl client certificate. As security mode i'm using transport security. It  is required that the authentication process is done by PeerTrust. Unfortunately transport security is not compatible with PeerTrust - this means that ChainTrust is always the preferred method. In this case every client is trusted which has a certificate signed by a CA which is stored in my "Trusted CA Store". That is not the behaviour that i need.

I've tried to fix this through a custom certificatevalidator. This seems to work. I get a callback with the certificate, and i can probably verify whether i trust the certificate or not.

My problem is that i'm not sure about the state when the certificate is provided to the "validate"-method within the custom validator. SSL usually checks by providing a client cert if the client has the corresponding private key. In other words, my problem is that i'm not sure, if the client i'm talking to, is the client that i think he is.

```
<serviceBehaviour>
    <behavior name="sslbehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="2000000000" maxConcurrentCalls="2000000000" maxConcurrentInstances="2000000000"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="Package.MyX509CertificateValidator, server"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```

Other approaches to get a PeerTrust client validation are welcome as well.

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: Having the following setting <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" /> should validate your client certificate only if it exists on your Servers Trusted People store else it would show a forbidden error. Also as you are using your custom validator you can map each certificate's thumbprint with  each client in db and once you get the call with the certificate fetch the clientId from db and store it in a session object which would help you to identify the client

Comment: "Having the following setting <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" /> should validate your client certificate only if it exists on your Servers Trusted People store else it would show a forbidden error." Are u sure about that? As far as i know this validation mode succeeds if a client cert is stored within trusted people or a root ca is installed on the server.

Comment: I have never tested it with multiple client certificates thought but not having the client certificate in the trusted people store on the server but having the issuer certificate did give me the error

Comment: Do you use Message or Transport security?

Comment: I use TransportWithMessageCredentials and my clientCredentialsType would be "Certificates"

Comment: Okay, as far as i know the means that u are using <security mode="Message">. In my case i have to use <security mode="Transport"> - The problem is, that transport security does not allow PeerTrust or PeerOrChainTrust (the default is ChainTrust)...

Comment: @Rajesh Can you please tell if I could use transport security or not to validate incoming client request for certificate? I mean.. should its public key be installed on trusted people to gain access or not ?

Comment: @Sandepku Yes you can have transport security and then on IIS you can set the SSL settings on your Virtual directory to be "Require SSL" checked with "Accept" radio button. In this way the request might or might not have a client certificate.

Comment: @Rajesh tried very had with this approach.. but not working.. instead i chose windows service instead of IIS, now I have custom validator for validating client certificate and check each and every other thing of the certificate !.. just that I need a way in IIS which currently I do not have

Comment: @Sandepku: What is that you have tried, is it setting the IIS SSL setting on the VD to be Accept and then use 2 way client cert authentication? Can you please post your configuration settings and more details like the error you are encountring. Might be as a different question to avoid confusion.